# Corner radius for UIView in UITableViewCell not working in iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIView in my custom UITableViewCell. I want to set the corner radius that depends on the height of that UIViews frame, Currently I have the following code:

```
 override func layoutIfNeeded() {
        super.layoutIfNeeded()
        subjectColorView.layer.cornerRadius = subjectColorView.frame.size.height/2
    }
```

This works perfectly in iOS10 but in iOS9 it doesn't round the corners at all. What am I doing wrong here? Where is the safest spot to be doing this type or view setup?

Comment: have you logged the `frame.size` of `subjectColorView`?

Answer (score 2):

try for clipping the UIView with the border radius.

```
subjectColorView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Tried this doesn't work. I think the error is in the RHS of the expression where I'm trying to get the height of a frame that hasn't been setup yet as if I change it to a constant such as 15 it rounds correctly.